# rning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS app that I've had since 2020 and it worked fast and well. When the domain expired in 2021, I forgot about it. Now as I was browsing files I found the app again and checked what it looked like so I ran `yarn` and `yarn start` only to find out that the components are not rendering anymore in the browser. I read a about the updates on ReactJS and found `vite`. My question is, do I need to re-write everything using `vite` or can I still use this site?

Here's the `Index.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "assets/styles/tailwind.css";

import App from './App';
import Privacy from './Privacy'
import Terms from './Terms'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { GraphQLClient, ClientContext } from 'graphql-hooks'

const client = new GraphQLClient({
  url: "https://graphql.datocms.com/",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": (process.env.REACT_APP_DATO_API_TOKEN)
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ClientContext.Provider value={client}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
        <Route path="/terms" exact component={Terms} />
        <Route path="/privacy" exact component={Privacy} />
        </Routes>
    </ClientContext.Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I added a dummy `p` tag in the `public/index.html` file:

```
  <body class="text-gray-800 antialiased">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <p>This paragraph is a part of HTML.</p>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

The text showed so I know I'm missing something here.

Comment: Did you check the console? Any errors there?

Comment: There are a lot of errors. The site is https://studio.vicentereyes.org/ now. The code can be seen at https://github.com/icvntechstudio/rebrand